# Is it possible to refer to List method from another method?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

My goal is:
[image]
Open blank fields for adding new data in this table.

I want to refer to List method from addNewUser method to add new User, this simply don't work, without any mistakes:

```
public void addNewUser(){
myList= getUsers();       // new list     
allValues = new Values(); // Values class with setters & getters           
allValues.setEditable(true); //boolean variable must open input fields in xhtml page
myList.add(allValues);
}
```

List method, which retreive inf. from DB:

```
static List<Values> valuesList;
static Values allValues;
static List<Values> myList;

public List<Values> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}

private static List<Values> getUsers(){
        try {
            databaseConnection();
        String SQL= "SELECT * FROM Registration";
        System.out.println("Retreive values from Registration table...");
        PreparedStatement prepStatement= connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        valuesList= new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet resultSet= prepStatement.executeQuery();
          boolean found= false;
          while(resultSet.next()== true){
              allValues= new Values();
              allValues.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
              allValues.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
              allValues.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
              allValues.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
              allValues.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
              valuesList.add(allValues);
               found= true;
          }
          resultSet.close();
          prepStatement.close();
           close(connection);
          if(found){
              return valuesList;
          }else {
            return null;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in getUsers()-->"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return (null);
    }

    public List<Values> getInformation(){
        return getUsers();
    }
```

Comlete class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean(name= "user")
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable{
      static final String JDBC_DRIVER= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      static final String DB_URL= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/updateTesting"; //newUsers
      static final String USER= "****";
      static final String PASS= "****";
      static Connection connection;
      static PreparedStatement prepStatement;
      static List<Values> valuesList;
      static Values allValues;

    private static List<Values> getUsers(){
        try {
            databaseConnection();
        String SQL= "SELECT * FROM Registration";
        System.out.println("Retreive values from Registration table...");
        PreparedStatement prepStatement= connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        valuesList= new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet resultSet= prepStatement.executeQuery();
          boolean found= false;
          while(resultSet.next()== true){
              allValues= new Values();
              allValues.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
              allValues.setOrderNo(resultSet.getString("orderNo"));
              allValues.setProductName(resultSet.getString("productName"));
              allValues.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
              allValues.setQty(resultSet.getInt("qty"));
              valuesList.add(allValues);
               found= true;
          }
          resultSet.close();
          prepStatement.close();
           close(connection);
          if(found){
              return valuesList;
          }else {
            return null;
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in getUsers()-->"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return (null);
    }

    public List<Values> getInformation(){
        return getUsers();
    }

    public static void databaseConnection() {
            try {
                Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
                //open connection
                   System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                   System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
         }catch(SQLException sqlEx){
             sqlEx.printStackTrace();//handle errors for jdbc
             System.out.println("Exeption occured in the process: "+sqlEx);
         }catch(Exception ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();//handle errors for ClassForName
             System.out.println("Exception occured in the process: "+ex);
            }
        }

    public static void close(Connection connect) {
        try {
            if(connect!= null){
            connect.close();
            }
        System.out.println("DataBase Connection closed!!!");
        System.out.println("Good bye!!!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
@ManagedBean(name="values")
@RequestScoped
public static class Values{
      private int id;
      private String orderNo;
      private String productName;
      private BigDecimal price;
      private int qty;
      private boolean editable;

 public Values(){
 }
 public Values(int id, String orderNo, String productName, BigDecimal price, int qty){
     this.id= id;
     this.orderNo= orderNo;
     this.productName= productName;
     this.price= price;
     this.qty= qty;
 }
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getOrderNo() {
    return orderNo;
}
public void setOrderNo(String orderNo) {
    this.orderNo = orderNo;
}
public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}
public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}
public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}
public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}
public boolean isEditable() {
    return editable;
}
public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
    this.editable = editable;
}

private List<Values> myList;

public List<Values> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}

public void addNewUser(){
myList= getUsers();           
allValues = new Values(); 
allValues.setEditable(true);
myList.add(allValues);
}
}
```

xhtml page:

```
<h:form>
 <center>
 <h:dataTable value="#{user.information}" var="x" border="1" id="table">
    <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Id"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.id}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Order No"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.orderNo}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Product name"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.productName}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.productName}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Price"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.price}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.price}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Quantity"></h:outputText>
     </f:facet>
     <h:inputText value="#{x.qty}" rendered="#{x.editable}"></h:inputText>
     <h:outputText value="#{x.qty}" rendered="#{not x.editable}"></h:outputText>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
     <h:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{values.dataDel(x.id)}"/>     
   </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
 <h:commandButton value="AddNew" action="#{values.addNewUser}" update="table"/>
 </center>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Do you mean as in `myList.add(allValues)` in `addNewUser()`? Yes, you can refer to `add()` (a list method) from another method (in this case `addNewUser()`). If you meant someting else, please explain.

Comment: My goal is to edit retreived from DB list, but addNewUser() don't work with getUser(). I haven't 'open input fields' like on picture...

Answer (score 0):

Ivan,

The code missed where the variables (myList, allValues) are defined.

It seems that those variables are global (not a good idea), because they are not defined in the example. Also check that getUsers() is static and addNewUser is not.

You need to provide that context for an answer to be useful.

Comment: I add myList, and allValues - it's class with variables, setters and getters. Is addNewUser must be static too?

Comment: Can you help me? where I need to prodide that contex?

Comment: Ivan, addNewUser doesn't need to be static to access myList and allValues, but you can't call addNewUser from another static method (without providing a instance of the class). Please provided the complete class to see what's the context. Can you describe what does "don't work" mean? (You receive a compile error, a runtime error, or the application does something different of what you expected). Also, the image you provided, is generated by this class, is it in an servlet, JSP, or other technology?

Comment: Carlos I provide comlete code, it's jsf. Is it quite clear - open 'input fields' for add new data in datatable, like on image???